# Excel, using part of the result of the formula within itself

Tags: excel

i am trying to set up a data-base search that relies on the presence of the dash within the cell. Here's the formula.

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"-",""))>1,SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "", 1),MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)-6,10))
```

It determines if the quantity of "-" sign is greater than 1 and if so, it substitutes the first dash with space(this is how i ignore its presence), if the amount of dashes is less, than it proceeds to extract a part of cell that has the following format ******-*** , 6 characters before dash and 3 characters after.

I'm facing two problems.

1. If there are two dashes in the cell, i want to substitute the first dash and then use the following result to extract my ******-***. I understand this can be done by simply running this script in a next column, but was curious if it's possible to perform these actions within one formula string.
2. Sometimes there are multiple dashes in the cell that are located after my ******-*** , which means the formula will erase the dash i need. I don't want to use Basic and brake my head scripting the pattern, so i was curious if there is something i can use formula-wise to make sure it uses the dash i need.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's an example.

```
1. Velocity RX23 Altitude P903L1-034 ND Pressure T87P5
2. Velocity RX23-Altitude P903L1-034 ND Pressure T87P5
3. Velocity RX23 Altitude P903L1-034 ND Pressure T87P5-
```

In first example, by using my original formula i get P903L1-034, the result i need.
Second string returns the modified version that does not have the first dash, but it also does not extract the P903L1-034 which i need.

`Velocity RX23Altitude P903L1-034 ND Pressure T87P5`

Third example returns a butchered version of the string that destroys P903L1-034 format.

`Velocity RX23 Altitude P903L1034 ND Pressure T87P5-`

I'm trying to extract the P903L1-034 from every possibility, obviously the actual database has different digits and numbers every time. While going thru database manually i noticed that 99% of the time it looks like example number 2 and i'm trying to make the single formula to ignore the first dash and convert the rest into P903L1-034.

Comment: Hi. Any chance of several example strings together with your desired result in each case?

Comment: Wrap it all in another IF() statement that tells it which way to go based on whether your target cell utilizes one or two dashes.  You already have the solution for IF('one dash' = TRUE, 'your formula', ...).  Now just write the second half modeled off the first.

Comment: I just added the example and a bit more explanation. Hope this make  more sense now =)

Answer (score 0):

I agree examples would be better but I think I understand.. not 100% sure though

Something like this?

Original    Converted

124568-452183 -------> 124568 452

4531-4268141 -------> 4531-4 268

458-45-3434 -------> 458-45 343

-4365-6543646----46 -------> -4365- 654

-4365--6543646----46 -------> -4365- 654

=LEFT(IF(MID(A2,7,1)="-",LEFT(A2,6)&" "&RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-LEN(LEFT(A2,6))-1),LEFT(A2,6)&" "&RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-LEN(LEFT(A2,6)))),10)

So, if the 7th character is a "-" we replace it with a " ", otherwise we add the " " in between the 6th and 7th. Then shorten the whole thing to 10 characters

Comment: Not exactly, sorry if i confused you. I'm trying to make sure that i receive the 6characters+dash sign+3 more characters. I've added the example to my original post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the solution. And it's a little larger than i thought, but it works.

```
=IF(LEN(IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"-",""))>1,IF(LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH("-",A1), SEARCH(" ",A1, SEARCH("-",A1))- SEARCH("-",A1)))=4,MID(C1,FIND("-",C1)-6,10),SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "", 1)),"Error"))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"-",""))>1,IF(LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH("-",A1), SEARCH(" ",A1, SEARCH("-",A1))- SEARCH("-",A1)))=4,MID(C1,FIND("-",C1)-6,10),SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "", 1)),"Error")),"-",""))>1,IF(LEN(MID(IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"-",""))>1,IF(LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH("-",A1), SEARCH(" ",A1, SEARCH("-",A1))- SEARCH("-",A1)))=4,MID(C1,FIND("-",C1)-6,10),SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "", 1)),"Error"), SEARCH("-",IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"-",""))>1,IF(LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH("-",A1), SEARCH(" ",A1, SEARCH("-",A1))- SEARCH("-",A1)))=4,MID(C1,FIND("-",C1)-6,10),SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "", 1)),"Error")), SEARCH(" ",IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"-",""))>1,IF(LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH("-",A1), SEARCH(" ",A1, SEARCH("-",A1))- SEARCH("-",A1)))=4,MID(C1,FIND("-",C1)-6,10),SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "", 1)),"Error"), SEARCH("-",IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"-",""))>1,IF(LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH("-",A1), SEARCH(" ",A1, SEARCH("-",A1))- SEARCH("-",A1)))=4,MID(C1,FIND("-",C1)-6,10),SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "", 1)),"Error")))- SEARCH("-",IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"-",""))>1,IF(LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH("-",A1), SEARCH(" ",A1, SEARCH("-",A1))- SEARCH("-",A1)))=4,MID(C1,FIND("-",C1)-6,10),SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "", 1)),"Error"))))=4,MID(IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"-",""))>1,IF(LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH("-",A1), SEARCH(" ",A1, SEARCH("-",A1))- SEARCH("-",A1)))=4,MID(C1,FIND("-",C1)-6,10),SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "", 1)),"Error"),FIND("-",IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"-",""))>1,IF(LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH("-",A1), SEARCH(" ",A1, SEARCH("-",A1))- SEARCH("-",A1)))=4,MID(C1,FIND("-",C1)-6,10),SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "", 1)),"Error"))-6,10),"Inspect Title"),"Error")
```

I made it to count how many characters there is after the dash and compare it, if it's the right quantity, then it extracts the data i need, if not, it ignores the first dash, finds second and uses it. The only other thing i can think that could be usefull is if i could count how many characters i have before the dash until space.

I use the following formula to count how many characters i have from dash to space in the right direction.

```
=IF(LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH("-",A1), SEARCH(" ",A1, SEARCH("-",A1))- SEARCH("-",A1)))=4,"Awesomesauce","Wrong")
```

Not sure how to reverse it and make it count in the left direction.